# How to update column with concatenation of other column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, concatenation

I have a table with 4 columns: Science, Math, English, and Classes.
Science, Math, and English are booleans, and Classes is nvarchar.

If Science is 1, then Classes should get appended with a semicolon and the string 001.
If Math is 1, then Classes should get appended with a semicolon and the string 002.
If English is 1, then Classes should get appended with a semicolon and the string 003.

So if Science was 1, Math was 0, and English was one, then Classes would have 001;003.
Or if Science was 0, Math was 1, and English was zero, then Classes would have 003.

I initially tried:

```
Update Table
SET Classes = CASE
                WHEN Science = 1 THEN concat(Classes, ';001')
                WHEN Math = 1 THEN concat(Classes, ';002')
                WHEN English = 1 THEN concat(Classes, ';003')
              END
```

But this won't work because as soon as the CASE finds a true statement, it updates that and won't check the other conditions. Can anyone help with figuring out how to do this kind of concatenation? Thanks!

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: I would change this into a computed column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 3 `CASE` expressions inside `CONCAT()`:

```
UPDATE Table
SET Classes = CONCAT(Classes, 
                CASE WHEN Science = 1 THEN ';001' END,
                CASE WHEN Math = 1 THEN ';002' END,
                CASE WHEN English = 1 THEN ';003' END
              )
WHERE 1 IN (Science, Math, English);
```

Comment: The `ELSE ''` is not even needed. (But it does not hurt to keep them)

Comment: @Luuk you' right. In SQL Server CONCAT() ignores nulls unlike other databases.

Comment: I just tried this and it worked! Thanks for the help :)
This'll be helpful to me as a SQL beginner

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server 2017 onwards.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Science BIT, Math BIT, English BIT, Classes VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT (NULL));
INSERT INTO @tbl (Science, Math, English) VALUES
(1, 0, 1),
(0, 1, 0);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

-- before
SELECT * FROM @tbl;

UPDATE @tbl
SET Classes = CONCAT_WS(';', IIF(Science=1, '001',NULL), IIF(Math=1, '002',NULL), IIF(English=1, '003',NULL))

-- after
SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

**Output**

```
+----+---------+------+---------+---------+
| ID | Science | Math | English | Classes |
+----+---------+------+---------+---------+
|  1 |       1 |    0 |       1 | 001;003 |
|  2 |       0 |    1 |       0 | 002     |
+----+---------+------+---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the slightly more compact `iif`

```
classes=
concat(
    iif(science=1,';001',''),
    iif(math=1,';002',''),
    iif(english=1,';003','')
)
```

Because in your question you indicate you don't want the first semicolon you can remove it with `stuff`

```
stuff(concat(
    iif(science=1,';001',''),
    iif(math=1,';002',''),
    iif(english=1,';003','')
),1,1,'')
```